# Hyperlink to open latest item in a document library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a document library that holds the company newsletter each month. On the main page of our Intranet I have a link that always goes to the latest version of this newsletter without my having to always update the link. I've done this by using a workflow  that updates a list whenever a new item is uploaded into the list - but is there another/better way around this problem?

Comment: Can you please tell me how you created the workflow to update the link to the new item added?
I've been trying to do the same but I guess I'm not very good at it. Thanks
Raza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a view of the list that is sorted by date descending and then limited to a single item?

Comment: Well I'll be.. how embarrassing that I didn't think of this :)

Comment: Don't be embarrassed mate, we all don't know all the possible solutions. This is the sole purpose of any discussion forum.